# Could I write a UI in Asp.Net Core for a Web Api written in the latest .Net Framework (4.8)?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

The Web API, written using the .Net Framework, uses MSDTC which Core doesn't support.

Is there any reason I couldn't write the font end using the latest Asp.Net Core 5 (or soon to be 6) MVC, Core + React, or Core + Angular?

I'm thinking there would be an issue deploying something like this b/c of the two different frameworks.

Thanks!

Comment: Why would there be a reason?

Comment: Mainly to start working in the new tech i.e. Core / React,  Core / Angular, or Core MVC but Im guessing deploying it wouldn't work b/c of the mixed frameworks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly then you have following thing.

1. Build Web API using .NET Framework 4.8 as it has some library support that you required for project.

   - Yes You can do this. You need .NET Framework 4.8 when you deployed and so you need Windows env. for that as .NET Framework 4.8 is not cross platform.
2. You want to use .NET Core, .NET 5 for front end.

- From here I assume that you will call Web API and you can definitely do that.
- For this you need .NET 5 or .NET Core 3.1 installed when you deployed. It may be same machine where you deployed Web API with .NET Framework 4.8.
- Front end only concern for request and response when it call API. It may be in same technology or any other technology provided it understand the request and response.

Comment: Wouldn't a typical deployment be the Web API and the UI on the same application server?  I guess I'm not sure the 4.8 framwork and .Net 5 can be on the same application server.

Comment: Both can be present side by side provided it is windows machine as .NET Framework 4.8 is not cross-platform.  Deployment can be vary depends on requirement like UI and Web API on same or different server.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use UI, why you not use MVC?

Web API uses **HTTP services** to **provide response** for the user and it can return more types of data than mvc.

So it does not have a view.

In Asp.Net Core 3.1 or before, you also can't write front end in web API.

[What is the Web API](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/webapi/web-api-tutorials)

Check [this link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/consuming-web-api-in-net-core-3-1-mvc/) to use MVC and Web API together.In mvc, call the Web API project, MVC will check

the response of Web API and take actions.

Comment: Correct, the web api is written already.  I was wondering if I could write the UI in something like Core MVC, Core & Angular, or Core & React to learn the new tech. But I dont think you could deploy it b/c you'd be mixing frameworks?

Comment: @CodeDonkey If it is mvc or it can have view page, youc can add UI. It's not about mixing frameworks, I edited the answer. The second link is the way to call existing api in mvc, not mixing frameworks.